# docker run throw error `No such file or directory` when use 2 commands

Tags: linux, docker

I found that if I use two commands, the second command cann't read the file in volume, (while the first can read it.) like that:

```
[root@iZu51 test]# echo 'hello world' >> /data/test/a.txt
[root@iZu51 test]# docker run --rm -v /data/test:/data debian:stretch-slim cat /data/a.txt
hello world
[root@iZu51 test]# docker run --rm -v /data/test:/data debian:stretch-slim cat /data/a.txt && cat /data/a.txt
hello world
cat: /data/a.txt: No such file or directory
[root@iZu51 test]# docker run --rm -v /data/test:/data debian:stretch-slim cat /data/a.txt; cat /data/a.txt
hello world
cat: /data/a.txt: No such file or directory
```

How to fixed it? or it's a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are running a command into docker and the second is outside of docker

**Try to use `bash -c` or `sh -c` depending on your sehll**

```
docker run --rm -v /data/test:/data debian:stretch-slim bash -c 'cat /data/a.txt && cat /data/a.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't a bug in Docker. You're just using it wrong. Specifically:

1. You're not quoting the `;` or `&&`, so your outer shell is interpreting them and Docker isn't seeing them.
2. Docker interprets the arguments to `docker exec` as the name of a program then its arguments, not as an arbitrary shell thing. If you want the inner shell to parse them, then you need to wrap them with `sh -c` or something like it.